# Are all collinearity preserving bijections from $\mathbb R^3$ to itself of the form $Ax+b$ for $A \in M_{3\times3}(\mathbb R)$ and $b \in\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Are all collinearity preserving bijections from $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}\RR^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ of the form $Ax+b$ for $A$ in $M_{3\times3}(\RR)$ and $b \in \mathbb R^3$?

In particular, let bijective $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ such that if $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb R^3$ are collinear then $f(a),f(b),f(c)$ are collinear. Prove or disprove that there exists $A$ in $M_{3\times3}(\mathbb R)$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $f(x)=Ax+b$.

My work so far:

Because $f$ is bijective, $f^{-1}$ exists, thus we can find
$a = f^{-1}((0,0,0))$, $b = f^{-1}((1,0,0))$, $c = f^{-1}((0,1,0))$, $d = f^{-1}((0,0,1))$
and construct the unique linear transform T such that
$a = T((0,0,0))$, $b = T((1,0,0))$, $c = T((0,1,0))$, $d = T((0,0,1))$
notice $g$ fixes $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$
Then let $g(x) = f(T(x))$, if we can show that $g$ is of the form $Ax+b$ then because $f(x) = g(T^{-1}(x))$ and $g$ and $T$ are both of the form $Ax+b$, then we will have show $f$ is of the form $Ax+b$, thus it is sufficient to consider a collinearity preserving bijection that fixes the origin and 3 standard basis vectors.

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Note the typographical difference between $3x3$ and $3\times3.$

Comment: thanks a lot Micheal, I'm not very good with mathJax yet, I did do a bit though, I used the $ a few times so its not as bad as it could have been (or at least its not as bad as some of my questions have been in the past). Also thanks Shaun, I'm reading the link you gave me right now